# AWS Android SDK not able to access s3 in "sub-directory"

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using the android sdk generated by AWS API Gateway to get a pre-signed URL for objects in s3 (lambda behind API gateway).

My s3 bucket looks like this:

```
* module_a
|\
| * file_a
| * subdir_a
|  \
|   * file_sa
* module_b
```

This works perfectly for *file_a*, but for *file_sa* it doesn't. At least not when I use the android SDK, there I get an URL where the slash is replaced with `%25252F`.
However, when I test the api in the console, I get the correct URL.

Is there anything I can do with the SDK to fix this?

**Update**

Here's the chain of code snippets involved in this problem.

*Android code to download file (exception happens in last line)*

```
fileName = "css/style.css"; // file in s3
moduleName = "main"; // folder in s3
[...]
ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory().credentialsProvider(
    aws.credentialsProvider);
apiClient = factory.build(myAPIClient.class);
apiClient.modulesModuleFileGet(fileName.replace("/", "%2F"), moduleName);
URL url = new URL(url_path.getUrl());
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

*API Gateway*

The api endpoint used above is configured with two path parameters (module name and file name). The body mapping template for the call to lambda looks like this:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "module" : "$input.params('module')",
  "file": "$input.params('file')"
}
```

*Lambda*

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import urllib
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        key = event['module'] + "/" + event['file'].replace("%2F", "/")
        url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
                "get_object",
                Params={'Bucket':"mybucket",
                        'Key': key},
                ExpiresIn=60)
        return {"url": url}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the code that generates the incorrect URL?

Comment: @Unsigned, jsut added more code, I hope it's not too much. I tried to show only the important stuff.

Comment: Why are you using replace() for escaping? If you need url encoding, you should do it properly with something like `URLEncoder.encode` or `urllib.parse.unquote`.

Comment: This is the outcome of three (!) levels of redundant (and at least 2 are incorrect) url-escaping  ("percent-encoding"):  `/` → `%2F` → `%252F` → `%25252F`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work after following the comments. However I still somehow get double quoted slashes. Here's the working code

#### Android

```
public Url modulesModuleFileGet(String fileName, String moduleName) {
    try {
        String fileNameEnc = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8");
        Url ret = getApiClient().modulesModuleFileGet(fileNameEnc, moduleName);
        return ret;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "> modulesModuleFileGet(", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Lambda

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
        key = event['module'] + "/" + urllib.unquote_plus(urllib.unquote_plus(event['file']))
        url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
                "get_object",
                Params={'Bucket':"my",
                        'Key': key},
                ExpiresIn=60)
        return {"url": url}
```

I'd still welcome further suggestions on how to improve this, but for now it is working. Thanks for the comments pointing me in the right direction.